# Linux и firefox

Tags: header, php, firefox, linux

Здравствуйте! Поставила в тупик такая ситуация. Есть некий сайт (наш) на PHP (Апач+Линукс). На сайте ссылка на скрипт PHP. Пользователь кликает по этой ссылке, скрипт, соответственно, запускается, выполняет своё дело и отправляет пользователю http заголовок для редиректа на другой сайт (header("Location: http://www.example.com);). Так вот у пользователей Windows всё работает как нужно. У большинства пользователей Linux, в общем-то, тоже. Но вот у некоторых линуксоидов с браузером firefox перенаправления на другой сайт не происходит.Собственно вопрос. В чём может быть причина?

Answer (score 2):

Просто в качестве догадки. В мозилле есть настройка [network.http.redirection-limit](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.redirection-limit), которая определяет максимальное количество перенаправлений. Если ее выставить в ноль, то запросы на редирект с сервера блокируются браузером. Возможно, продвинутые пользователи Linux поменяли для себя эту настройку.